# How to install a godaddy SHA-2 wildcard cert Into Domino

Tags: lotus-notes

I have bought a godaddy wildcard SHA-2 cert for an organization. I now need to install that into a domino server but can’t find any good information or procedure for doing so.

I am using latest version of Domino 9.0.1 FP9 on Windows

Thanks

Comment: Cross-Site-Duplicate: https://serverfault.com/questions/918218/how-to-install-a-godaddy-sha-2-wildcard-cert-into-domino

Answer (score 1):

1. Generate private Key (if you do not have one already)
   `openssl genrsa -out server.key 4096`
2. Generate CSR with private key
   `openssl req -new -sha256 -key server.key -out server.csr`
3. Get Certificate
4. Create server.txt containing following files:

- private key (server.key)
- certificate from CA (server.crt or something like that)
- Intermediate Certificates (intermediate.crt )
- Root Certificate (root.crt)
  Intermediate and root may be available as a bundle too.

Verify server.txt:
`kyrtool =c:\lotus\notes\notes.ini verify c:\lotus\notes\data\ssl\server.txt`

Then do the following steps:
5. Generate KYR- File (=Container for Key and Certificates)
`kyrtool ="c:\Program Files\IBM\Notes\notes.ini" create -k "c:\Program Files\IBM\Notes\data\keyring.kyr" -p password`

6. Import into kyr file
   `kyrtool =c:\lotus\notes\notes.ini import all -k c:\lotus\notes\data\keyring.kyr -i c:\lotus\notes\data\ssl\server.txt`
7. Copy kyr and sth in Domino- Data and put name of kyr- file in Serverdokument or Internet Site document
8. Restart HTTP

Comment: there is a lot of confusion for me, I have a .pfx file, .crt file and a .p7b file

Comment: I find this guide more helpful, I will update when I know more
http://www.infoware.eu/tag/wildcard-ssl